# Disable System.Text.Json on Web API on .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I would like explicitly use *legacy* `Newtonsoft.Json` library for serialization/deserialization on .NET Core Web API 3.0.0. No mater what I do, always `System.Text.Json` is involved and custom Newtonsoft's converters are not used.

`ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs` looks like this:

```cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
// ...
            services.AddControllers()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                    {
                        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                        options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
                        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomGeoJsonConverter());
                    }
                );
// ...
}
```

In this case I tried with custom `CustomGeoJsonConverter` and, while serializing, there were no activity in that object. Similar code works OK in .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: Do you have a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`?

Comment: Yes, because method `AddNewtonsoftJson` is part of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` assembly.

Comment: I think you are wrong. Try installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package in your API layer explicitly  and the issue should go away.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: I have Same problem.